# Zoom map out to contain the given map bounds

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map app and the user is able to perform a marker search. 
The search has the current mapBounds so that I can search only in the current view. However, if I don't have any results in the current view - I'm trying to do a search within 100km of the center of the map.

If I find location within 100km I want to zoom out the map in order to show the locations I've found.

On the server I go through all my locations and get the sw and ne points. So basically in my ajax response I can directly create latLngBounds (no need to loop through the markers locations and extend the bounds).

The issue is whenever I try to do map.fitBounds(mynewbounds); nothing happens. The map stays as it is.

It seems that since the center of the map is the center of the new bounds, the map doesn't want to move. If I do map.pantobounds then the map moves to the northwest corner of the bounds.

The behavior of pantoBounds is expected according to the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

```
If the bounds is larger than the map, the map will be shifted to include the northwest corner of the bounds
```

Any ideas how to make the map zoom out in order to contain the new bounds?

Comment: So when you add a new marker via AJAX you are not updating the bounds? But you are trying to do `fitBounds` without the new marker?

Comment: I have the coordinates for my new bounds. The ajax response has the new boundaries so I create them like this:
   var myBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
 new google.maps.LatLng(data[0].boundaries.s,data[0].boundaries.w),
   new google.maps.LatLng(data[0].boundaries.n,data[0].boundaries.e));

It works (I've drawn a rectangle to see where the new bounds are, and they are correct). Unfortunately the map doesn't move to show them...

Comment: Here are few screenshots to illustrate the issue.  
1. https://www.diigo.com/item/image/48vz2/c4qu - here everything is fine as we have locations in the current view.

2. https://www.diigo.com/item/image/48vz2/wvp8 - here I'm zoomed in. No locations in the current view, but in the 100km search radius there are locations. However fitbounds doesn't zoom out to show them.

3. https://www.diigo.com/item/image/48vz2/i7cx - this shows what happens when I use panToBounds... which is not helpful either.

4. https://www.diigo.com/item/image/48vz2/op0v - this is what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I just figured out what is going on. Right before I set the boundaries I was trying to remove my zoom_out and dragend events. Unfortunately I opted in for using the clearListeners event, which was removing all events set on the map (even the one that are not set by me). So it seems that fitBounds issues are zoom_changed event, but the map was not responding to it, as all listeners were removed.

Once I removed the correct events by using removeListener(listenerInstance) the fitBounds function started to behave as expected.

So just as a warning to everyone else! Don't use clearListeners if you don't know what you are doing. It removes all events assigned to the map object which can lead to nasty behavior!